# Replacing a Null Character with other character in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc

In this code:

```
  int main()
{
    char arr[5]="knot";
    char *ptr, *ptr1;
    int i;
    ptr = &arr[1];
    ptr1 = ptr + 3;
    *ptr1 = 101;
    for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        printf("%c", *ptr++);

    return 0;
}
```

The output happens to be `note`.

What I understand is the line, `ptr = &arr[1];` points `ptr` to the second memory location of the original array and `ptr1 = ptr + 3;` points `ptr1` to where the null character(`'\0'`) is stored in the original array. 
After that `*ptr1 = 101;` replaces the null character(`'\0'`) in the original array with `e`. After that I am printing from where `ptr` is pointing upto 4 characters.

What I've interpreted the code is something like this

[image]

What I don't understand is, though I am replacing the null character(`'\0'`) with some other character, why does

```
puts(arr);
```

or

```
for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
   printf("%c", arr[i]);
```

still prints `note`, and not some garbage value after printing `e`. In the second for loop statement I tried printing the array beyond it's scope and it still prints `note`.

Could it be that the memory locations after `e` just contains whitespaces? And is it safe to print a string/ character array like this in the future?

PS: I am using gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

Comment: Both `puts(arr)` (after removing the null-terminator) and accessing the array out of bounds invoke *undefined behavior* - anything can happen at that point, including a seemingly correct result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Could it be that the memory locations after `e` just contains whitespaces?*

Not exactly, but the value `0`, which acts as a null terminator. So, somehow the functions handling strings are *showing* seemingly proper behaviour. For the loop and accessing individual element case anyways, attempting to access memory location which is not allocated to the process (i.e., not a valid memory) is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> *And is it safe to print a string/ character array like this in the future?*

**ABSOLUTELY NOT**. The result you got is out of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), it's neither guaranteed nor reliable.

Comment: can strings in C be either `0` terminated or Null(`'\0'`) terminated ?
Thanks a ton for clearing my doubt though.

Comment: @zeroSpook the value of `'\0'` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happened to be the case for your instance. I replicated your code the following way:

```
for(i=0 ; i<25 ; i++){
    printf("%c", *ptr++);
}

printf("\n--------\n");


for(i=0 ; i<25 ; i++){
    printf("%c", arr[i]);
}

printf("\n--------\n");

i=0;
while(arr[i] != '\0'){
    printf("%c",arr[i++]);
}
printf("|");
```

and got the following

[image: output]

Probably better to not print using the for method you used. It will give you inaccurate result and possibly result in security issues not to mention there is a good chance of miscounting.

I personally think its better to stick with puts or while(arr!='\0') or if using a for loop set the stop condition to sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char)

Comment: Yup I observed that too, when I changed i<10 to i<50 or i<100, some random characters shows up in the o/p. I guess it is just 'undefined behavior' as the previous answer pointed out.